# How can I use Equinox Weaving with bndtools

Tags: osgi, aspectj, equinox, load-time-weaving, bndtools

How can I use `equinox Weaving` with `bndtools` because the `equinox Weaving` example is old and can't get it to work?

update:

when trying to run the weaving sample for Hello world

I have two bundles:

```
public class HelloService  implements BundleActivator {

    public void start(final BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }



    public void stop(final BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Good bye world!");
    }
}
```

bnd.bnd

```
-buildpath:  \
osgi.core,\
osgi.cmpn,\
biz.aQute.bnd.annotation,\
${junit}
Bundle-Version: 0.0.0.${tstamp}
Require-Bundle: helloaspect
Export-Package:  \
com.weaving.hellohistorytest
Bundle-Activator: com.weaving.hellohistorytest.HelloService
```

aspect bundle:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class HelloAspect  {

/**
 * Replaces the "Hello world!" output with "Hi from HelloAspect ;-)".
 */
@Before("execution(* HelloService+.*(..))")
public void advice() {
   System.out.println("hello aspect");
}
}
```

bnd.bnd

```
-buildpath:  \
osgi.core,\
osgi.cmpn,\
biz.aQute.bnd.annotation,\
${junit},\
aspectjrt-1.7.3,\
aspectjweaver,\
org.eclipse.equinox.supplement
Bundle-Version: 0.0.0.${tstamp}
Service-Component:  \
    *
Export-Package:  \
com.weaving.helloaspect;aspects="HelloAspect"

Eclipse-SupplementBundle: com.weaving.hellohistorytest
```

launch.bndrun

```
runbundles:  \
org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,\
org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,\
org.apache.felix.gogo.command,\
org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj,\
org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook,\
aspectjweaver,\
aspectjrt-1.7.3,\
osgi.cmpn,\
osgi.core,\
cnf.run.equinox.common,\
org.apache.felix.framework,\
osgi.enterprise,\
org.eclipse.equinox.supplement,\
    helloaspect;version=latest,\
hellohistorytest;version=latest,\

-runproperties:\
osgi.framework.extensions=org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook


 -runrequires:\
 osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.apache.felix.gogo.shell)',\
 osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.apache.felix.gogo.command)'

-runvm: -Dosgi.framework.extensions=org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook,\
-Daj.weaving.verbose=true,\
-Dorg.aspectj.weaver.showWeaveInfo=true,\
-Dorg.aspectj.osgi.verbose=true
```

when i run the launch:
I get Hello world not hello aspect
also, Aspect Weaving Hooks Plug-in (Incubation)  is set Resolved

what is the problem?

Comment: still didn't get any help

Comment: Suggested proceeding (assure that the Aspect is still running after each step)

(1) Try to get the example from git repo working (either 3.x or 4.x).

(2) Remove the other environment

(3) Remove the other Aspects (keep only the one you want to use)

(4) Add your bundles
(5) Adapt the Aspect to modify your bundles

The topic is quite complex and getting things right is very tidious. That is why I provided the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/peterkir/example.aspectj)

Comment: @PeterKirschner.Thanks for your help.why if i add a constructor inside aspect class like this 
 `int x,y,z;
 public AfterAspect(int _x,int _y,int _z){
  x=_x;
  y=_y;
  z=_z;
 }` before `@After("execution (* example.aspectj.app.Application.methodToModify(..))")
 public void methodAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint) ` it prints **starting AspectJ Demo application**
**calling methodToModify with param <Hi RCP World!>**
**"Hi RCP World!** 3 times without entering the **methodAfter** inside aspect ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An working source-code example can be found here on [GitHub](https://github.com/peterkir/example.aspectj)

Generally the instructions [here](https://www.eclipse.org/equinox/incubator/aspects/equinox-aspects-quick-start.php) are also valid for usage with bndtools.

Add the required bundles

```
-runbundles: \
  org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj,\
  org.aspectj.runtime,\
  org.aspectj.weaver
```

Make sure that the org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook is co-located

```
-runpath: org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook
```

And the you need to provide the following runproperties inside the *.bndrun

```
-runproperties:\
   osgi.framework.extensions=org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook
```

The following runtime properties are optionally available for debugging. Note that the output goes always to std.err stream even if they work normally).

```
aj.weaving.verbose=true,\
org.aspectj.weaver.showWeaveInfo=true,\
org.aspectj.osgi.verbose=true,\
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter Kirschner.I tried your steps,but when i launch OSGI,it print "Hello World" from the sample not "Hi from HelloAspect".should I include the aop.xml with -includeresource in bnd?.I still can't get it to work.Could you please give me a complete sample running with bndtools?

Comment: I try to get my old example (Eclipse 3.8) working with Eclipse Mars or Luna as IDE. Facing strange issues. Will give it a try with the old environment. Update is following this week.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Kirschner.I hope to find update this week with a working example using bndtools.

Comment: .I really appreciate your help and i will give it a try.

Comment: @ Peter Kirschner: when i run 3.10.x_explicit.bndrun, I got : org.aspectj.weaver.tools.Jdk14Trace error SEVERE: register definition failed example.aspectj.bnd.app] warning register definition failed -- (RuntimeException) Cannot register non aspect: example$aspectj$explicit$AfterAspectJ **example.aspectj.explicit.AfterAspectJ**

Comment: Did you set the appropriate target definition? Are you using the same IDE setup? AspectJ and the tooling is very delicate.

Comment: I'm using eclipse luna v.4.4 with j2se_1.8 ( 1.7 not working either) and bndtools v. 2.4.1.So,I run **launch_org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.x_explicit.bndrun**.Is that correct?

Comment: I will try with bndtools 2.4. What AJDT tooling, you are using? The one I reference is bugfixed by spring.io The officially available by Eclipse AJDT site fit Luna was not working.

Comment: I'm using the one you referred to in github.

Comment: Really thanks,It was my fault.I got it to work.I have a last question.could I write my aspects in .java files?

Comment: Sorry @yehia, I don't know if it is feasible to use pure java files for AspectJ.

Comment: Sorry for opening questions again.I have a case where I have three bundles.one containing an interface extending another one with a save method.the next one call the save method available from the first bundle when pressing a button.the last one is the aspect class which be called after executing the save method.The question here is , which bundles  shall be woven beside the aspect one, i mean the target bundles for weaving(Eclipse-SupplementBundle) the first which extend the interface (save method) or both?

Comment: Create a new question for it.